# global dictionary python when using pool.map()

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def process_chunk(d):
if (d):
    d = d.split(" ")
    for value in d:
        if value not in dictionary.values():
            dictionary[len(dictionary)] = value
    print(dictionary)            
return 1

def grouper(n, iterable, padvalue=None):
     return izip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=padvalue)




dictionary = {}
if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_data = open('testfile.txt').read() 
    test_data = test_data.split("\n")
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)


for chunk in grouper(2, test_data):
    results = p.map(process_chunk, chunk)
```

When I call function process_chunk(d), the variable "dictionary" will become empty. I want to put all results into dictionary:
suppose I got the result each time:
    dictionary = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
    dictionary = {0: 'a', 1: 'd'}
    dictionary = {0: 'e', 1: 'f'}

I want to get 
    dictionary = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3:'d',4:'e', 5:'f'}
in other words, make the dictionary global.
how should I fix it?

Comment: Why not _return_ the value (instead of putting it into a dictionary) and then build the dictionary after the `p.map` is done?  Multiprocessing doesn't do well with global data since each process has it's own copy of the data.  If you actually want to share data between processes, you need to use a `Manager`, but that probably cuts down on some of the gains you get from using multiprocessing because you need to spend time communicating between processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `global dictionary` at the beginning of your `process_chunk` function, but it's not good practice to use globals. You better either pass it into function calls or create a class and put it as a private member.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to pass dictionary to process_chunk function:     process_chunk(d, dictionary)                                             
results = p.map(functools.partial(process_chunk, dictionary_list), chunk)   
however,  variable d is empty while chunk is not empty? Why this might happen?

Comment: can you provide a more complete example? how do you use the global variable? are you sure you're actually inserting something into it? make sure you have a statement like this: `global dictionary` at the beginning of `process_chunk(d)`